# NSCFString objectAtIndex unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc16bad0

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code :

```
NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:CatTitle];

    NSLog(@"%@",items);
    menu = [[BlurMenu alloc] initWithItems:items parentView:self.view delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"I'm here !");
    isMenuCat = TRUE;
    [menu show];
```

When **NSLog** "items" getting result fine :

> (
>           "\U0627\U0646\U0642\U0637\U0627\U0639 \U062c\U0632\U0626\U064a",
>           "\U0627\U0646\U0642\U0637\U0627\U0639 \U0643\U0644\U064a",
>           "\U062d\U0631\U064a\U0642",
>           "\U0645\U0634\U0643\U0644\U0629 \U062e\U0627\U0635\U0629 \U0628\U0627\U0644\U062c\U0647\U062f"
>       )

I am using library which create blur menu, in `BlurMenu.m` file :

```
- (id)initWithItems:(NSArray*)items parentView:(UIView *)p delegate:(id<BlurMenuDelegate>)d {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        int i = 0;
        NSMutableArray *temp_Arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSArray *xx in items) {
            [temp_Arr addObject:[xx objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSLog(@"%@",[xx objectAtIndex:i]);
            i++;
        }

        userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userData setBool:NO forKey:@"isTwice"];
        [userData synchronize];

        self.parent = p;
        self.delegate = d;
        self.menuItems = temp_Arr;

        self.alpha = 0.0f;
        self.frame = p.frame;

        UIImage *background = [self blurredSnapshot];
        UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
        [self addSubview:backgroundView];

        CGFloat height = [self calculateCollectionViewHeight];

        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        [layout setMinimumLineSpacing:ITEM_LINE_SPACING];
        _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (self.frame.size.height - height) / 2, self.frame.size.width, height) collectionViewLayout:layout];
        [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
        [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
        [_collectionView registerClass:[BlurMenuItemCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
        [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self addSubview:_collectionView];

        UIButton *close = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        close.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - COLLECTION_VIEW_PADDING, self.frame.size.width, COLLECTION_VIEW_PADDING);
        close.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [close setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [close setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        close.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:18.0f];
        [close addTarget:self action:@selector(hide) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [self addSubview:close];

    }
    return self;
}
```

This is the line where the error happens :

```
menu = [[BlurMenu alloc] initWithItems:items parentView:self.view delegate:self];
```

Here is the error :

> -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc16bad0
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc16bad0'

Comment: Point out the line giving you the error. The error is clear though. You have an `NSString` instance where your code assumes there is an `NSArray`.

Comment: @rmaddy I pointed to it .. thanks in advance

Comment: That can't be the line. It is most likely the 1st line inside the for-loop inside the `initWithItems:parentView:delegate:` method.

Comment: It is kind of that line since that's where BlurMenu is being initialized and triggering the initWithItems: method containing that other code... But yeah, the xx in that loop is probably a string and causing the error.

Comment: Actually it's definitely a string as apparent in your NSLog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `NSLog` of `items` indicates, `CatTitle` is an array of strings; so when you pass it into `initWithItems:` and access its contents with this loop

```
int i = 0;
NSMutableArray *temp_Arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSArray *xx in items) {
    [temp_Arr addObject:[xx objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[xx objectAtIndex:i]);
    i++;
}
```

you're treating it like an array of arrays, but since "xx" isn't actually an array but a string, it results in the `NSInvalidArgumentException` you've received.

So you can try this instead to add your strings to `temp_Arr` with a loop:

```
NSMutableArray *temp_Arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSString *xx in items) {
    [temp_Arr addObject:xx];
    NSLog(@"%@", xx);
}
```

But really, that's unnecessary since you can simply copy the `items` array into `temp_Arr` with a single line of code:

```
NSMutableArray *temp_Arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:items copyItems:YES];
```